# Syntax error near unexpected token `/' when substracting timestamps

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm totally new to bash and unix, so the answer to this might be very simple, but despite googling for quite some time I didn't find the solution.

What I'm trying to do is to calculate a difference in days between 2 dates. However, when I convert each date to  an epoch second and try to subtract them I get the "Syntax error near unexpected token `/" error.

Here's the script:

```
# obtain date provided by user in the following format "YYYY-MM-DD"^M
POPULATE_FROM=$2^M
POPULATE_TO=$3^M
#obtain task name^M
TASK=$1^M
FILE_NAME=$(echo $TASK | cut -d'.' -f1)^M
# obtain current date^M
CURRENT_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)^M
echo "Current $CURRENT_DATE"^M
POPULATE_FROM_DATE=$(date -d "$POPULATE_FROM" +%s)^M
CURRENT_DAY=$(date -d "$CURRENT_DATE" +%s)^M
POPULATE_TO_DATE=$(date -d "$POPULATE_TO" +%s)^M
echo "Current date $CURRENT_DAY"^M
echo "Populate From date $POPULATE_FROM_DATE"^M
echo "Populate to date $POPULATE_TO_DATE"^M
# calculate dates difference in days^M
DIFF_FROM=($POPULATE_FROM_DATE - $CURRENT_DAY) / 86400^M
echo $DIFF_FROM^M
DIFF_TO=($POPULATE_TO_DATE - $CURRENT_DAY) / 86400^M
if ((DIFF_FROM < 0)) ; then^M
  # revert it so difference is a positive int^M
  DIFF_FROM=$((0-$DIFF_FROM))^M
  DIFF_TO=$((0-$DIFF_TO))^M
  for ((i=$DIFF_FROM;i>$DIFF_TO;i--));^M
  do^M
    TASK_DATE="$(date "+%Y-%m-%d" -d "$i days ago")"^M
    TEMP_FILE_NAME="$FILE_NAME-$TASK_DATE.json"^M
    echo $TEMP_FILE_NAME^M
^M
    # copy content of the base task to a new file in order not to overwrite it^M
    cp $TASK $TEMP_FILE_NAME^M
^M
    TASK_NAME="$FILE_NAME-$TASK_DATE"^M
    sed -i "s/$FILE_NAME/$TASK_NAME/" $TEMP_FILE_NAME^M
^M
    # replace "T-1" with "T-i"^M
    DAY_PATTERN='"IMAS.Loaders.Date" : "T-1"'^M
    NEW_DAY_PROPERTY='"IMAS.Loaders.Date" : "'"T-$i"'"'^M
    sed -i "s/$DAY_PATTERN/$NEW_DAY_PROPERTY/" $TEMP_FILE_NAME^M
^M
    # remove the scheduled cron expression^M
    sed -i '/ScheduleExpression/d' $TEMP_FILE_NAME^M
^M
  done^M
else^M
  echo "Provided date is in the future, no action performed"^M
fi^M
```

Here's the execution:

```
bash script.sh "fileName" "2019-08-20" "2019-08-21"
```

And here's the output I get:

```
Current 2019-08-22
Current date 1566428400
Populate From date 1566255600
Populate to date 1566342000
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "line 17: 1566255600

")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "line 19: 1566342000
'script.sh: line 24: syntax error near unexpected token `
'script.sh: line 24: `  for ((i=$DIFF_FROM;i>$DIFF_TO;i--));
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks almost like you have dos line endings `\r` in your shell script. Inspect your file with `cat -v` or `hexdump` and try `dos2unix`. Remember to quote your variables `echo "$TASK"` and `"$TEMP_FILE_NAME"` and `cp "$TASK" "$TEMP_FILE_NAME"`. Also you don't need to use `$` inside `((` `))` expansion, just `((i = DIFF_FROM;   i > DIFF_TO; i--))`

Comment: @KamilCuk: I've updated the script with what cat -v printed out, there don't seem to be any \r chars

Comment: See thos all `^M` on the end of lines. Those are dos line endings. Run your script via dos2unix.

Answer (score 0):

As it says, line 17 is wrong.. Its not a valid syntax.

Use this:

```
DIFF_FROM=$(($(($POPULATE_FROM_DATE - $CURRENT_DAY)) / 86400))
```

This line define the `DIFF_FROM` variable which will be used in the other lines below.

Comment: No it's valid. There is little sense to do arithmetic expansion inside arithmetic expansion. just `DIFF_FROM=$(( POPULATE_FROM_DATE - CURRENT_DAY) / 86400))` or even `(( DIFF_FROM  = ( POPULATE_FROM_DATE - CURRENT_DAY) / 86400 ))` is ok.

Comment: The error in line 17 is that it needs to be quoted or else enclosed as an arithmetic expression (preferably using `$((…))` syntax). The shell will trip over line 17's first `(` or the spaced `/`. @KamilCuk is also right in that you don't need nested arithmetic expressions.